# Need a VBA module to loop through word files, find something, and report it in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Start module. Be presented with file picker dialog and choose a bunch of files. Files always have an 8 digit ID at the beginning of the name, but the rest of the name is variable.
2. Find ALL strings of the form "T0***" in the word file and store them in an array.
3. Open up an excel spreadsheet (one spreadsheet for the entire macro). Report the file ID in A1, and spit out the string of find results in B1.
4. Close that word file; open the next one in the list and repeat the process. Report its results in A2 and B2 of the spreadsheet. Do this until the end of the selected list of word files.

There can be any number of T0*** strings.

So far I've got it opening up each file and then closing it. That's as far as I'm able to get. Any help is much appreciated!

```
'Toolfind Macro

Sub ToolFind()
Dim idarray
Dim FileSelections
Dim j As Integer
' ------------------------------------------------------

Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 500) As String
On Error Resume Next
Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)



Set Ex0 = New Excel.Application
    Set Wb0 = Ex0.Workbooks.Add




' ---------------------------------------------------------------
' *.doc? allows processing of *.doc and *.docx files.
' ---------------------------------------------------------------
With MyDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.doc?", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True

i = 1
If .Show = -1 Then
For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
i = i + 1
Next

i = i - 1
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For j = 1 To i Step 1
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
Set ID = Left(GetStr(j), 8)






Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If

If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------'

Dim k As Long, SmArr()
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "T0***"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    k = k + 1
    ReDim Preserve SmArr(k)
    SmArr(k) = .Text
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With

'go into EXCEL'

    Wb0.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value (ID)
    Wb0.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value (SmArr)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'-----------------------------------------------------------------------




ActiveDocument.Close (wdSaveChanges)
Next j
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `SmArr` is not reset between loops. it will be carrying forward all of the data from previous loops. You'll want to `Erase SmArr` at the end of the loop.

Comment: To view the file after you're done, do `Ex0.Visible = True`. To save the file with or without making it visible, do `Wb0.SaveAs "FileName"`

Comment: To make the macro output to different rows of the workbook, you can add `.Offset(j - 1)` to the end of the ranges like `Wb0.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(j - 1).Value = ID`. Btw, you need an "=" sign to assign the value. And you don't need the brackets.

Comment: Made those changes. But the module still isn't doing anything... it opens and closes each word file, and then opens a blank excel file and ends.

Comment: `k` also should be reset between loops. As for why SmArr isn't filled with values... I don't know enough about MS Word VBA to help any further... sorry!

Comment: Please read this help doc about how to ask a question that will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For some code to get you started, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/59665-post2.html. Note that the code is run from Excel, which is more sensible when you're trying to collate data there from multiple documents.